# Retrieve data from a Cursor

Tags: java, android, database, cursor

I have a database with only one table : notifications (which contains an id, a title, a note, etc)
I'm trying to have an Activity that displays the title of the notifications through a ListActivity. And when the user clicks on one of the title, it displays the whole notification.

I have a Cursor that retrieves data from the database :

```
public Cursor getAllNotifications() {
return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
        KEY_DAYOFWEEK, KEY_HOUR_BEG, KEY_HOUR_END, KEY_ROOM,
        KEY_TEACHER, KEY_NOTE}, null, null, null,
        null, null);
}
```

In the class that extends ListActivity, I have a `private String[] notificationsList;`

but I don't know how to retrieve the data because the getAllNotifications() method returns a Cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
cursor.getString(/**columnindex**/);
```

And similar functions :
Refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html